# Simple select option set_value in codeigniter

Tags: codeigniter, bootstrap-4

I have simple select for gender option :

```php
<select class="form-control show-tick" name="kelamin" required="true">
 <option value="">-- Please select --</option>
 <option value="L" >Laki-Laki</option>
 <option value="P">Perempuan</option>
</select>
```

How to set_value on select option like

```html
<input type="text" name="nama" class="form-control" value="<?= set_value('nama'); ?>" required="true">
```

Answer (score 0):

Use the [set_select](https://codeigniter.com/user_guide/helpers/form_helper.html#set_select) function.

```
<select class="form-control show-tick" name="kelamin" required="true">
        <option value="" <?= set_select('kelamin', '', TRUE); ?> >-- Please select --</option>
        <option value="L" <?= set_select('kelamin', 'L'); ?> >Laki-Laki</option>
        <option value="P" <?= set_select('kelamin', 'P'); ?> >Perempuan</option>
</select>
```